# Load image from inside a project folder and Display in jsf popup

Tags: java, arrays, inputstream

in my requirement i have a image in my project folder, if database does not contain image i have show the default image in popup

The default image is not displaying its showing empty 
 [image: please refer image]

Every thing working fine for database image 
  [image: working image form database]

after clicking the PDF button it executes following method:

```
public void getImage(ExpenseTO to) {
        ExpenseTO fetchEntityById = accountService.fetchEntityById(
                ExpenseTO.class, to.getExpenseId());
        byte[] fileScanned = fetchEntityById.getUploadedScanedFile();
        if (fileScanned.length <= 20) {
            try {
                ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread()
                        .getContextClassLoader();
                InputStream input = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("file.png");
                byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(input);
                outPutPdfToDisplay = new DefaultStreamedContent(
                        new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            outPutPdfToDisplay = new DefaultStreamedContent(
                    new ByteArrayInputStream(fileScanned));
        }
    }
```

it executes with out any exception but not not displaying
 image in popup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i got solution for this

with help of JSF

hear is my code:

```
public void getImage(ExpenseTO to) {
        ExpenseTO fetchEntityById = accountService.fetchEntityById(
                ExpenseTO.class, to.getExpenseId());
        byte[] fileScanned = fetchEntityById.getUploadedScanedFile();
        if (fileScanned.length <= 20) {                     
                outPutPdfToDisplay=null;            
        } else {
            outPutPdfToDisplay = new DefaultStreamedContent(
                    new ByteArrayInputStream(fileScanned));
            }
    }
```

and the dialog is:

```
<p:dialog widgetVar="test" id="dialog" position="300,10"  draggable="true"  modal="true" resizable="false" closable="true">
                    <p:media rendered="#{accountsHomeBean.outPutPdfToDisplay != null}" value="#{accountsHomeBean.outPutPdfToDisplay}" width="700px" height="700px" player="pdf" cache="false" />
                    <h:graphicImage value="/images/file.png"   rendered="#{accountsHomeBean.outPutPdfToDisplay == null}"/>
                </p:dialog>
```

if the image is present in database `<p:media>` tag is executes
else if image is null in database it will executes `<h:graphicImages>`

[image: its look like]